# Нужна ли запятая после Иванов И.И.? Почему?

Tags: пунктуация

Ответственным за контроль за обучением по охране труда Иванова И.И., назначить заместителя начальника отдела Петрова П.П.

Comment: В цитате, есть уверенность, не хватает слов. Можете расширить рамки цитируемого из «действующего документа»?

Comment: Точно нужны пробелы между инициалами.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужна ли запятая после Иванов И.И.? Почему?

Не нужна. Потому что нет причин её там ставить. 
А из чего вы-то исходите, предполагая что запятая может быть "нужна"?!

Comment: Я исхожу из того, что запятая стоит в действующем документе

Comment: @Любовь Ааааа ))). Понял. Ну тогда можете считать её ошибкой.